# how tooltip-html-unsafe works? is there any issues ?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying with tool tips i come across this "tooltip-html-unsafe" concept.  Can any one help me how it works and is it recommend to use or it under goes any cross site scripting issues (XSS).

Thanks in Advance.